# How to query to generate result

Tags: sql-server

[Data of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3cqu.png)

Using query :

```
SELECT CustomerID, product_type, api
FROM Test_Policy
ORDER BY CustomerID ASC
```

[Output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/862OC.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: What value you wants in the field no_whole and others?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT to get your desired output as below

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ee7c58beacec901e9bea02398d72ef8)

```
WITH CTE(customerId, product_type,api)
AS
(
    SELECT customerId, product_type,api 
    FROM your_table
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT customerId, product_type,product_type+'_2' product_type_2,api 
        FROM CTE
    )P
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(product_type)
        FOR product_type IN ([whole life],[endownment],[saving])
    )PVT
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(api)
        FOR product_type_2 IN ([whole life_2],[endownment_2],[saving_2])
    )PVT2
)

SELECT customerId,
ISNULL(SUM ([whole life]),0) AS no_whole,
ISNULL(SUM ([endownment]),0) AS no_endow,
ISNULL(SUM ([saving]),0) AS no_sav,
ISNULL(SUM ([whole life_2]),0) AS api_whole,
ISNULL(SUM ([endownment_2]),0) AS api_endow,
ISNULL(SUM ([saving_2]),0) AS api_sav
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY customerId
```

Output will be something like below-

```
customerId  no_whole    no_endow    no_sav  api_whole   api_endow   api_sav
001         1           1           1       10000       10000       10000
002         1           0           0       10000       0               0
003         0           0           1       0           0           10000
004         2           0           2       10000       0           10000
```